# how to custom heatmap cell with padding?

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I try to reach the padding between cell border and cell content for some cell. But i can't style the `<rect>` element.

I use highcharts v4.2.5. And tried almost options to custom data cell such as stroke, strokeWidth, pattern filling.

I also tried use 2 overlap  elements for one data point as following:

```
<rect x="0"
      y="0"
      width="20"
      height="20"
      stroke="black"
      stroke-width="1"
      fill="white">
```

```
<rect x="3"
      y="3"
      width="14"
      height="14"
      stroke="black"
      stroke-width="0"
      fill="url('#custom-pattern'">
</rect>
```

but this options need override the way highcharts render heatmap cell. i'm still trying this way.

This [cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16LEh.png) is what i want to achive.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: I use highcharts v4.2.5. i tried add padding for `<rect>` and also tried almost options to custom data cell such as `stroke, strokeWidth, pattern filling`... I also tried use 2 overlap `<rect>` elements for one data point  as following
`<rect x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white"></rect>
<rect x="3" y="3" width="14" height="14" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="url('#custom-pattern'"></rect>`
but this options need override the way highcharts render heatmap cell. i'm still trying this way. are you have any advises?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pointPadding` (see https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.heatmap.pointPadding).

I modified the Highcharts heatmap demo with this option (see https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/qtbof29x/):

```
 series: [{
    name: 'Sales per employee',
    pointPadding: 10,
    data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000'
    }
}]
```

[image]

Depending on how you want the final version to look, another solution you could try instead is increasing the `borderWidth` and changing the `borderColor` to mimic cell padding.

I hope this information is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but i still want to keep the border of original cells.

Comment: You absolutely can with `pointPadding`. The example above has a border width of 0. If you updated the code with both `pointPadding` and a `borderWidth` of 1 or greater, you would see both the border and the cell padding.

Comment: To amend my comment, the solution I think you're looking for is better solved using `gridLineWidth` for your axes ... I realized `borderWidth` will draw a box around the heatmap cells, but will still be pushed in by the padding. Here's a second version of my fiddle with the grid lines serving as the cell borders: https://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/ormh3qke/

Comment: yes. But gridLine is configure by axes. i need for some cells with null value only.

Comment: @CorundHope Should those cells with null values have no borders?

Comment: Incase it stay alone and around it is cells with slightly color. Then it look better if have border. i'm trying to wrap `translate` method for heatmap hope to have result soon.

Answer (score 1):

Based on existing rects elements, you can render another, which will imitate border. In this case you will also have to use pointPadding.

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      points = series.points,
      pointPos,
      padding = series.options.pointPadding;

    if (series.rects) {
      Highcharts.each(series.rects, function(rect) {
        rect.destroy();
      });
    }

    series.rects = [];

    Highcharts.each(points, function(point) {
      pointPos = point.shapeArgs;

      series.rects.push(chart.renderer.rect(
          pointPos.x + chart.plotLeft - padding,
          pointPos.y + chart.plotTop - padding,
          pointPos.width + padding * 2,
          pointPos.height + padding * 2)
        .attr({
          fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
          stroke: 'black',
          'stroke-width': 1,
          zIndex: 3
        })
        .add());
    });
  }
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1r8d95js/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect